# ROS Answers SE migration: Car dynamics

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently in a formula student team and I am really interested in learning more about the car's dynamics (eg how to simulate the car movement inside gazebo). It would be great if I could get resources to learn more about this (and also if possible, a "learning path") as I am a bit struggling with knowing where to start.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394256/car-dynamics/) by [KhalidOwlWalid](https://answers.ros.org/users/80061/khalidowlwalid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2022-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A lot of open-sourced material from the TUM winners of Indy Autonomous Challenge are in repositories mentioned in [this ROS Discourse post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/tum-wins-1m-indy-autonomous-challenge-open-sources-everything/22834).

There is also this [post](https://discourse.ros.org/t/course-self-driving-cars-with-ros-2-and-autoware-auto/13955) with a really nice intermediate introduction to an intermediate-level course from the Autoware Foundation for individuals who develop pre-production autonomous driving systems.

There is this [SVL SIMULATOR](https://www.svlsimulator.com/) Unity-based multi-robot simulator for autonomous vehicle developers from LG Electronics America R&D Lab too ([repository](https://github.com/lgsvl/simulator)).

This post is nice too: https://www.theconstructsim.com/start-self-driving-cars-using-ros/.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KhalidOwlWalid](https://answers.ros.org/users/80061/khalidowlwalid/) on 2022-01-14**:
Ahh thank you for this wonderful answer!